# Not able to show ToDo list in JSP

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to spring boot and trying to create a simple ToDo Application using spring boot and JSP. I am trying to show the list of todo's in my JSP but it is not reflecting. I tried all the ways whereas on putting breakpoint in IntelliJ idea, I am able to see the list of todo's in my repo.

```
ToDoView.jsp

 <%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="navigation.jsp"%>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="/add-todo">Add Todo</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>List of TODO's</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="40%">Description</th>
                        <th width="40%">Target Date</th>
                        <th width="20%"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                ${todolist}
                    <c:forEach items="${todolist}" var="todo">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${todo.description}</td>
                            <td>${todo.getDescription()}</td> <td><fmt:formatDate value=${todo.getToDoDate()} pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>
                            <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="/update-todo?id=${todo.getId()}">Update</a>
                             <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="/delete-todo?id=${todo.getId()}">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
```

```
HomeController.java

package com.toDoApp.ToDoApp;

@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @Autowired
    ToDoRepo repo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public static String home()
    {
        return "Home";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/list-todos", produces = {"application/json"})
    public String toDoView(Model m)
    {
        m.addAttribute("todolist", repo.findAll());

        return "ToDoView";
    }
}
```

```
ToDoRepo.java

public interface ToDoRepo extends JpaRepository<ToDoList, Integer>
{

}
```

```
ToDoList.java

package com.toDoApp.ToDoApp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class ToDoList
{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private Date toDoDate;

    public ToDoList()
    {
        super();
    }

    public ToDoList(String description, Date toDoDate)
    {
        super();
        this.description = description;
        this.toDoDate = toDoDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getToDoDate() {
        return toDoDate;
    }

    public void setToDoDate(Date toDoDate) {
        this.toDoDate = toDoDate;
    }
}
```

I tried all other ways but didn't able to find anything. Please help me out.

Thank You

Comment: can you share your pom.xml maybe you haven,t inserted tomcat dependency

Comment: Here is the link to pom.xml file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PR5KdySp132cLhCaopUHBRlmwoArDISq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is what I am getting on frontend - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqfHCKKkgFl4LSfz_CVIOVRoQiE2v3XW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the jasper Dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and change the td tags like this

${todo.getDescription()}

Comment: I added the dependency in the pom.xml file and also did the change in the JSP file but nothing happened.

Comment: try to use Model instead of ModelMap in HomeController and use m.addAttribute instead of put

Comment: Tried Model instead of ModelMap. No change in result. I am not getting it why it is happening.

Comment: Have you created the Object of repository in Home Controller?

Comment: can you send you full jsp file and home Controller code?

Comment: <td>${todo.getDescription()}</td>
                            <td><fmt:formatDate value=${todo.gettoDoDate()} pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>
                            <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="/update-todo?id=${todo.getId()}">Update</a>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="/delete-todo?id=${todo.getId()}">Delete</a></td>

Comment: try this way i think this will help because you have used getters and setters

Comment: No sir it didn't worked

Comment: I edited my post and added whole file. Please have a look. @Janil101

Comment: add this taglib line in your jsp file at top <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: What is this code <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> being used for?
And in jsp what do I use? Your code or old code?

Comment: this is a taglib which we use in jsp to run java code like for loop and all

Comment: I changed the code and it is working now. I am getting target date and description in frontend. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If my code has worked give a tick I need one

Comment: Please update your answer, so that others must know what worked for this problem. I am upvoting it.
Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: okay I will update my code

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

try adding jasper dependency

Comment: I added the dependency but it didn't worked.

Comment: Explainations on why this dependency work / is better would help understand the anwser